# Element wise 'in' for pandas with a Series of Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-3.6

I have about 30 columns for which I am looking to change a value if that value is in that row for a column of lists.  This is a little hard to describe verbally so here is some code for what I'm talking about:

```
test = test.groupby('RealId')['Player'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Invalids')
test.index = te["RealId"]
test.drop("RealId", axis='columns', inplace=True)
test = test.join(te, on="RealId", how="left")

test['PA_14'].isin(test['Invalids'])
```

The PA_14 column is a normal Series of strings, while Invalids is a Series of lists of strings. What I would like is for that last line to output a boolean vector, but isin() doesn't appear to work with a series of lists.  How I do this relatively quickly considering that it needs to be done 30 more times?

Comment: kindly add sample data to ur question, as well as expected output.data, not pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line actually tests for each element (str) of `test['PA_14']` if it is one of the elements (list) of `test['Invalids']`. 
You can try:
`boolean_index = [s in list_s for (s, list_s) in zip(test['PA_14'], test['Invalids'])]`